# Datagrid добавить строку для заполнения сверху

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-datagrid

Есть не редактируемый `DataGrid` у которого `ItemSource` присвоен `BindingList`. Все столбцы `DataGrid` текстовые кроме одного `CheckBox`.

Сейчас заполнение ведется с помощью отдельно стоящих `ComboBox`, `CheckBox` и кнопки добавить. Элементов с учетом кнопки меньше на 1 чем столбцов в `DataGrid`. Возможно ли поместить эти `ComboBox` в первую строку `DataGrid`?

Пробовал поместить в XAML разметке и это удавалось, но программа не запускалась из-за присвоенного `ItemSource`. Так же есть идея просто задать первую строку в `BindingList` пустой и просто смотреть за ее изменениями. Если нельзя добавить в первую строку тела таблицы, то может можно добавить между телом таблицы и заголовком?

Comment: `Возможно ли поместить эти combobox в первую строку DataGrid?` В какую такую строку, о чем речь? Может имеется ввиду в первый столбец? Если да, то задайте явно эти столбцы в нужном вам порядке. Если речь про ваши органы редактирование, то что мешает их поместить перед `DataGrid`? Ну и на сколько я знаю, у `DataGrid` есть свои элементы добавления в таблицу (вроде).

Comment: Столбцы у DataGrid заданы и есть элементы управления для добавления данных в DataGrid. Элементы управления и хочется запихнуть под заголовки таблицы. Сейчас они и так помещены перед DataGrid. У DataGrid есть CanUserAddRow, но он всегда снизу списка и мне не надо делать весь столбец combobox, а только в строке добавления.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в WPF, не используйте `BindingList`, он для Winforms, используйте `ObservableCollection` вместо него.

Comment: Кстати, зачем вам `DataGrid`, если он не редактируемый? Используйте `ListView`. А так, чтобы решить эту задачу, вам нужно переопределить шаблон `DataGrid`. Но с точки зрения логики интерфейса, ваше требование выглядит странно.